# How to detect style change of an HTML element with YUI3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, styles, yui3

The site I'm working on is using a flaky ads provider and sometimes the JS code they return is buggy, e.g. ends up changing the background color of entire `body` element instead of its own `div` element. Unfortunately we have to use their service and it takes ages for them to correct such bugs.

So, I was thinking about creating a workaround, e.g. when the `body` element's `background-color` style is changed, my callback function would be called to change it back to correct value. Is there a clean way to do it with YUI3 (or jQuery, or pure JS if YUI3 doesn't have it)?

I know I can set the background periodically to correct color with `setInterval()`, but it seems wasteful and messy to me. Anyone know a better way?

Comment: How about using a background image on repeat so if they change the color, it doesn't matter because you have a tiled background anyway. Or perhaps you can move the background property declaration into another tag? Instead of `body` how about `hmtl` or the first div nested in the body? Just some thoughts.

Comment: @ProfileTwist I already have a background image on repeat, but it defines a gradient on the top, so it has `repeat-x` but no `repeat-y`.  I don't see how to make it repeat in two dimensions. I can't set the background color on `html` because it's overridden by `body`'s style. I don't have a single `div` element containing all the content, but I will check if it's possible to add it. Anyway, thanks for the ideas, I like them :) The ad server is inserting `html, body, #someid { background-color: whatever }` into my code, I think they meant `html body #someid`...

Comment: Instead of detecting "change" why don't you have you have a script and simply undo the damage? If you know html, body, #someid can be affected, why not run them through a grinder and change their settings? If I were you I would rather spend time yelling at the AD developer and tell them to fix it like right now. Changing such a small bug should only take like 30 minutes on their end. And that's a signficant screw up

Comment: The yelling part is done already and they will fix it eventually, but in the mean time our users were getting a broken page and I had to fix it ASAP... it's fixed now, but I was looking for a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are changing CSS through javascript, you can use [Mutation Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Events/Mutation_events) (Second Level Events).

You can listen on those events :

- DOMAttrModified
- DOMAttributeNameChanged
- DOMCharacterDataModified
- DOMElementNameChanged
- DOMNodeInserted
- DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument
- DOMNodeRemoved
- DOMNodeRemovedFromDocument
- DOMSubtreeModified

So either listen on DOMAttrModified, with **Style** attribute, or **Class** attribute.

Comment: This looks like a good and clean solution for the problem, but unfortunately the browser support is really weak :( Thanks, anyway.

Comment: @szeryf Your welcome, try to google some poly fills maybe you will be lucky.